# Multiple patterns for listing files using command line

Tags: windows, cmd

Inside my working directory I have files named after the year, month, day and hour of retrieval, like this:

```
19980101.00.nc 19980101.03.nc 19980101.06.nc 19980101.09.nc
19980101.12.nc 19980101.15.nc 19980101.18.nc 19980101.21.nc
19980102.00.nc 19980102.03.nc 19980102.06.nc 19980102.09.nc
19980102.12.nc 19980102.15.nc 19980102.18.nc 19980102.21.nc
19980103.00.nc 19980103.03.nc 19980103.06.nc 19980103.09.nc
19980103.12.nc 19980103.15.nc 19980103.18.nc 19980103.21.nc
```

And using the windows command line I would like to be able to operate with only this files:

```
19980101.15.nc  |
19980101.18.nc  |
19980101.21.nc _|_ # these are day 01 files
19980102.00.nc  |
19980102.03.nc  |
19980102.06.nc  |
19980102.09.nc  |
19980102.12.nc _|_ # these are day 02 files
```

So far I've used the command: `dir 19980101.*.nc` in order to list `19980101` files but I don't know how to omit the non desired files (I only need *19980101.15.nc, 19980101.18.nc and 19980101.21.nc* files form day *01*). Moreover, I haven't figured out how to combine in a single list file's names of day two (02 files) and files of day one (01 files).

Any thoughts?

Comment: So are you going to write a computer program?

Comment: @DavidGrayson No. I'm not going to write a computer program. I just need to list the files in order to apply NCO operators.

Comment: How about you run `dir` followed by the list of the 8 files you are interested in?  Or copy those files to their own directory and use `dir *`?

Comment: how do you define "desired"?

Comment: @DavidGrayson That would be impractical. I have exactly 55521 files and need to aggregate them using NCO operators listing only those like the ones in the example (in the example I combined day 01 and 02 files, from then I should combine 02 and 03 files then 03 and 04 etc. for every month and every year)

Comment: @Stephan As showed in the example I just need `19980101.15.nc 19980101.18.nc 19980101.21.nc`files leaving out `19980101.00.nc 19980101.03.nc 19980101.06.nc 19980101.09.nc 19980101.12.nc` files.

Comment: so you need 3 out of 8 "01"  files and 5 out of 8 "02" files. Do you have a list for all days? If not - how to decide *which* files?

Comment: @Stephan The files needed for each combination follow the same pattern: `yyyymmUU.15` `yyyymmUU.18` `yyyymmUU.21` for day 'UU' and `yyyymmVV.00` `yyyymmVV.03` `yyyymmVV.06` `yyyymmVV.09` `yyyymmVV.12` for day 'VV'

Comment: `dir C:\folder\??????01.* C:\folder\??????02.*`

Comment: @ACatInLove That will show files for all years and months for days "01" and "02".

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear, but here is nevertheless a commented batch file which prompts the user for a file date like `19980102`, determines the previous day for input date and runs **DIR** with the 8 files to print.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Prompt user for date string until a number string with exactly 8 digits is entered.

:EnterFileDate
set "FileDate="
set /P "FileDate=Enter date in format YYYYMMDD: "

rem Has the user nothing entered at all?
if not defined FileDate goto EnterFileDate

rem Has the user entered a string not consisting of only digits?
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("!FileDate!") do goto EnterFileDate

rem Has the user entered a too long string?
if not "%FileDate:~8%" == "" goto EnterFileDate

rem Has the user entered a too short string?
if "%FileDate:~7%" == "" goto EnterFileDate

rem Has the user entered a string not starting with 19 or 20 for century?
if not "%FileDate:~0,2%" == "19" if not "%FileDate:~0,2%" == "20" goto EnterFileDate

rem Don't care of possible other invalid date strings, but
rem check if the entered date string matches any existing file.
if not exist "%FileDate%.??.nc" (
    echo/
    echo There is no file "%FileDate%.??.nc".
    echo/
    goto EnterFileDate
)

rem Discard local environment and pass entered file date
rem to previous environment restored by command ENDLOCAL.
endlocal & set "FileDate=%FileDate%"

set "PrevYear=%FileDate:~0,4%"
set "PrevMonth=%FileDate:~4,2%"

rem Get day in month subtracted by 1 with avoiding to get 01 to 09
rem interpreted as octal number by concatenating this two digits
rem of day in month first with 1 for integer number 101 to 132.
set /A PrevDay=1%FileDate:~6,2% - 101

rem Is day in month greater or equal 1, month must not be changed.
if %PrevDay% GEQ 1 goto BuildPrevDate

set /A PrevMonth=1%PrevMonth% - 101

rem Is month less than 1, year must be changed too.
if %PrevMonth% LSS 1 (
    set /A PrevYear-=1
    set "PrevMonth=12"
    set "PrevDay=31"
    goto BuildPrevDate
)

rem Determine last day in new month and year.
if %PrevMonth% ==  1 set "PrevDay=31" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  3 set "PrevDay=31" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  4 set "PrevDay=30" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  5 set "PrevDay=31" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  6 set "PrevDay=30" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  7 set "PrevDay=31" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  8 set "PrevDay=31" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% ==  9 set "PrevDay=30" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% == 10 set "PrevDay=31" & goto BuildPrevDate
if %PrevMonth% == 11 set "PrevDay=30" & goto BuildPrevDate

rem Leap year finding for the years 1901 to 2099.
set /A LeapYear=PrevYear %% 4
if %LeapYear% == 0 (
    set "PrevDay=29"
) else (
    set "PrevDay=28"
)
set "LeapYear="

:BuildPrevDate
if %PrevDay% LSS 10 set "PrevDay=0%PrevDay%"
if %PrevMonth% LSS 10 set "PrevMonth=0%PrevMonth%"
set "PrevDate=%PrevYear%%PrevMonth%%PrevDay%"
set "PrevDay="
set "PrevMonth="
set "PrevYear="

echo/
dir %PrevDate%.15.nc %PrevDate%.18.nc %PrevDate%.21.nc %FileDate%.00.nc %FileDate%.03.nc %FileDate%.06.nc %FileDate%.09.nc %FileDate%.12.nc
set "FileDate="
set "PrevDate="
echo/
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`